# Custom wordpress theme, different text boxes admin users can edit?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I'm fairly new to developing custom Wordpress theme (though i've a fair amount of PHP experience). I've got the general gist of how it works, setting it up etc.

What I want to do is on the the home page have 4 images with captions underneath. I've used get_post() to pull in all content typed by a Wordpress admin user for the home page and fit it into the theme I'm creating, however what I can't figure out is how to set specific sections of text, so that they can be assigned to different parts of the page.

Essentially what i want is to have the captions under the 4 images be editable by WP admin users

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take help from these tutorials. Also, these tutorials will help you to take your theme development to next level.
http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/
http://ottopress.com/2012/making-a-custom-control-for-the-theme-customizer/
These two tutorials will definitely help you.

Comment: Thanks dude, 2nd one was what I was after (customizer setting)